# How do I use the output of a program from an earlier part of a Stack/Cabal build as source in a later part of the same build?

Tags: haskell, build, cabal, ffi, haskell-stack

I have a very peculiar dependency situation that I would like to package up in a single Stack/Cabal package: I need to build and run my program to get the input to a code-generator which produces output that needs to be linked in to... my program.

OK so in more concrete terms, here are the steps manually:

1. `stack build` to install all dependencies, and build all non-Verilator-using executables.
2. `stack exec phase1` to run the first phase which generates, among other things, a Verilog file and a Clash `.manifest` file.
3. I have a custom source generator, which consumes the `.manifest` file from step 2, and produces C++ code and a `Makefile` that can be used to drive Verilator.
4. Run the `Makefile` generated in step 3:

   1. It runs Verilator on the Verilog sources from step 2, which produces more C++ source code and a new `Makefile`
   2. Then it runs the newly generated second `Makefile`, which produces a binary library
5. `stack build --flag phase2` builds the second executable. This executable includes `.hsc` files that process headers produced in step 2, and it links to the C++ libraries produced in step 4/2.

I would like to automate this so that I can just run `stack build` and all this would happen behind the scenes. Where do I even start?!

To illustrate the whole process, here is a self-contained model:

## `package.yaml`

```
name: clashilator-model
version: 0
category: acme

dependencies:
  - base
  - directory

source-dirs:
  - src

flags:
  phase2:
    manual: True
    default: False

executables:
  phase1:
    main: phase1.hs

  phase2:
    main: phase2.hs
    when:
    - condition: flag(phase2)
      then:
        source-dirs:
          - src
          - _build/generated
        extra-libraries: stdc++ 
        extra-lib-dirs: _build/compiled
        ghc-options:
          -O3 -fPIC -pgml g++
          -optl-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
          -optl-Wl,--whole-archive -optl-Wl,-Bstatic
          -optl-Wl,-L_build/compiled -optl-Wl,-lImpl
          -optl-Wl,-Bdynamic -optl-Wl,--no-whole-archive

        build-tools: hsc2hs
        include-dirs: _build/generated
      else:
        buildable: false
```

## `src/phase1.hs`

```
import System.Directory

main :: IO ()
main = do
    createDirectoryIfMissing True "_build/generated"
    writeFile "_build/generated/Interface.hsc" hsc
    writeFile "_build/generated/Impl.h" h
    writeFile "_build/generated/Impl.c" c
    writeFile "_build/Makefile" makeFile

makeFile = unlines
    [ "compiled/libImpl.a: compiled/Impl.o"
    , "\trm -f $@"
    , "\tmkdir -p compiled"
    , "\tar rcsT $@ $^"
    , ""
    , "compiled/Impl.o: generated/Impl.c generated/Impl.h"
    , "\tmkdir -p compiled"
    , "\t$(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<"
    ]

hsc = unlines
    [ "module Interface where"
    , "import Foreign.Storable"
    , "import Foreign.Ptr"
    , ""
    , "data FOO = FOO Int deriving Show"
    , ""
    , "#include \"Impl.h\""
    , ""
    , "foreign import ccall unsafe \"bar\" bar :: Ptr FOO -> IO ()"
    , "instance Storable FOO where"
    , "  alignment _ = #alignment FOO"
    , "  sizeOf _ = #size FOO"
    , "  peek ptr = FOO <$> (#peek FOO, fd1) ptr"
    , "  poke ptr (FOO x) = (#poke FOO, fd1) ptr x"
    ]

h = unlines
   [ "#pragma once"
   , ""
   , "typedef struct{ int fd1; } FOO;"
   ]

c = unlines
   [ "#include \"Impl.h\""
   , "#include <stdio.h>"
   , ""
   , "void bar(FOO* arg)"
   , "{ printf(\"bar: %d\\n\", arg->fd1); }"
   ]
```

## `src/phase2.hs`

```
import Interface
import Foreign.Marshal.Utils

main :: IO ()
main = with (FOO 42) bar
```

## Script to run the whole thing manually

```
stack build
stack run phase1
make -C _build
stack build --flag clashilator-model:phase2
stack exec phase2
```

Comment: I think one possible angle of attack would be to write the whole process using Shake, merging steps 2 to 4. However, that still leaves me with the problem of running `stack build` again in step 5 with a `stack exec`  in-between...

Comment: separate step 1 and step 5 into 2 packages, add a shake script that handles step 2 to 4, add a custom Setup.hs in the second package that first invokes the first package, and then the shake script.

Comment: We can probably simplify the model even further, by saying `phase1` outputs `src/phase2.hs`.

Comment: Why is it important that this be a single package?

Comment: @DanielWagner it doesn't need to be a single package, but the end result should be one package containing, basically, both `phase1.hs` and another program that depends on `Interface`. But `Interface.hs` &c. could be in a different package.

Comment: I am now experimenting with generating a full Cabal package (`package.yaml` and `Setup.hs` and all) myself, in a subdirectory, and having `phase2` depend on that package. [It doesn't quite work yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61585694/477476) but it's a promising direction.

Comment: But why is it important that `phase1` and this other program be in the same package? The structure gets much, *much* simpler without that restriction, and it isn't obvious to me that the restriction serves any real purpose.

Comment: I'll need to write it up as a proper SO answer, but basically I got it working by [editing `otherModules`, `extraLibDirs` and related settings](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clashilator/blob/87bb5c2f160fde03bb80e717ba56a9ceb4039c92/src/Clash/Clashilator/Setup.hs) in my `Setup.hs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **The yak is fully bare**: I managed to solve it with a custom `Setup.hs`.

1. In `buildHook`, I basically do whatever `phase1` was supposed to do (instead of leaving it in a `phase1` executable), putting all generated files in places below the `buildDir` of the `LocalBuildInfo` argument. These generated files are C++ source files and an `.hsc` file.
2. I then run `make` in the right directory, producing some `libFoo.a`.
3. Still in `buildHook`, now the fun part starts: editing the `Executable`s in the `PackageDescription`.

   I add the `hsc` file's location to `hsSourceDirs`, and the module itself to `otherModules`. Since `hsc2hs` requires access to the generated C++ headers, I also add the right directory to `includeDirs`. For the library itself, I add to `extraLibDirs` and edit `options` to link statically to `libFoo.a`, by passing flags directly to the linker.
4. The result of all this is a modified set of `Executable`s, which I put back into the `PackageDescription` before passing it to the default `buildHook`. That one then runs `hsc2hs` and `ghc` to compile and link the `phase2` executables.

I have put a [full example project on Github](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clashilator-example/tree/a4ad624a12d35d59eeb70b85c9f116d0a8dd791e). Look at `Setup.hs` and `clashilator/src/Clash/Clashilator/Setup.hs` to see this in action; in particular, here is the editing of the `Executable`s in the `PackageDescription`:

```
-- TODO: Should we also edit `Library` components?
buildVerilator :: LocalBuildInfo -> BuildFlags -> [FilePath] -> String -> IO (Executable -> Executable)
buildVerilator localInfo buildFlags srcDir mod = do
    let outDir = buildDir localInfo
    (verilogDir, manifest) <- clashToVerilog localInfo buildFlags srcDir mod

    let verilatorDir = "_verilator"
    Clashilator.generateFiles (".." </> verilogDir) (outDir </> verilatorDir) manifest

    -- TODO: bake in `pkg-config --cflags verilator`
    () <- cmd (Cwd (outDir </> verilatorDir)) "make"

    let incDir = outDir </> verilatorDir </> "src"
        libDir = outDir </> verilatorDir </> "obj"
        lib = "VerilatorFFI"

    let fixupOptions f (PerCompilerFlavor x y) = PerCompilerFlavor (f x) (f y)

        linkFlags =
            [ "-fPIC"
            , "-pgml", "g++"
            , "-optl-Wl,--whole-archive"
            , "-optl-Wl,-Bstatic"
            , "-optl-Wl,-l" <> lib
            , "-optl-Wl,-Bdynamic"
            , "-optl-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
            ]

        fixupExe = foldr (.) id $
            [ includeDirs %~ (incDir:)
            , extraLibDirs %~ (libDir:)
            , options %~ fixupOptions (linkFlags++)

            , hsSourceDirs %~ (incDir:)
            , otherModules %~ (fromString lib:)
            ]

    return fixupExe
```

Comment: What does “The yak is fully bare” mean? Is that an idiom?

Comment: @JeremyCaney: if you look at my question and the eventual solution, you can see there was a LOT of [yak-shaving](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/388236/7804) involved!